# ReturnUrl in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I currently have a login link on my application that looks something like this:

```
<a href="/login?ReturnUrl=" + <%= Request.RawUrl %>>Login</a>
```

I want to handle the POST command on the login page in the controller action below:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    // Authenticate user

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

The problem here is if the RawUrl is something with multiple url parameters like "somepage?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3", then the returnUrl that gets passed into the Login action is truncated after the first ampersand: "somepage?param1=1".

I've tried UrlEncoding the RawUrl but that seem to make any difference.  It seems that the ASP.NET MVC framework here is UrlDecoding the url params before mapping them to the controller action parameters, which ends up stripping off the additional url parameters I want to see in my returnUrl parameter.

Is there any way around this?  I know I could just use Request.Path and parse out the values I need, but I thought I'd see if there was a cleaner approach first.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're probably encoding the links incorrectly. Yes, they do need to be encoded. Here is how we do it:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Delete", "TimeRecord", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { id = timeRecord.AltId, 
    returnUrl=ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery }) ) %>">
```

Comment: This is good; PathAndQuery doesn't include the domain, so you're not vulnerable to an attacker using your server to redirect to their site.

Comment: I wouldn't say you're not vulnerable. People can change the form data with Fiddler and the like. You still have to sanitize the URI at the server. On the other hand, it's good to not pre-populate the form with bad data. :)

Comment: Looks good.  Beware though that `ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url` can return null, meaning that you may have a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer to this question.  The correct answer is the one using `Url.Encode(Request.RawUrl)`

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you URL encode the RawUrl before using it.

```
<%= Url.Encode(Request.RawUrl) %>
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: This works fine, the original post mis-analysed what was happening.