# Redirect to originally requested page after Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have added an ActionFilter to my MVC site which checks if a user is currently logged on, by checking against a session value, if they are not, they are redirected to a login page.  The action filter attribute is added to each controller, so regardless of the page the user tries to view they are redirected to the login view.  This bit all works fine.

When the user successfully logs in, I want them to be redirected to the page they were trying to originally access, but I don't how to get my Login Post action to know where to redirect too.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello @andyJ. In future, do not post tags in question title.

Answer (score 2):

You send along a ReturnUrl when you go to the login view. Then the action method for the login view uses that value to know where to return. The following may help:

[ReturnUrl in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778607/returnurl-in-asp-net-mvc)

as well as this

[ASP.NET MVC - CustomeAuthorize filter action using an external website for loggin in the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835672/asp-net-mvc-customeauthorize-filter-action-using-an-external-website-for-loggin)

Comment: Any solution for the samecase in either php or jsp?