# Redirecting to a specific controller after logging in from a specific page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using the default MVC app, and I've started adding **[Authorize]** to certain controllers so users that try to access them will get the login screen and then will be redirected upon authentication.

One thing I can't figure out is how to handle this for controllers that have anonymous access, particularly my **HomeController**.  From this page, when a user clicks "login" and authenticates and the user is redirected back to the HomeController again.

What I want to happen is when the user clicks login on this page only, is for the user to be sent to the login page, and upon successful authentication they are directed to another controller.

I know the login layout is in _LoginPartial.cshtml, but I'm not sure how and **if** I this is  the place to add this feature.

**EDIT**

I suppose I could use the ViewBag object and pass in a ReturnURL to the layout, and use an @if statement to show a different actionlink.  How would you modify the following to specify a returnurl?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
```

Comment: did you try 'return RedirectToAction?

Comment: There is a returnURL in the AccountController, but I've no idea on how to set that from the HomeController page

Comment: Are you using Forms Auth? Can't you override the authentication process to look at the referer and redirect accordingly?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778607/returnurl-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes I'm using forms Auth.  Mike, how does that link let me specify the new returnUrl?

Answer (score 0):

To direct the user to another action/controller you could edit the action "[HttpPost], LogOn" in the AccountController. For example use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "SomeOtherControllerName")
```

**Update:**

If you want to set the returnUrl specifically, like in your example, it's done with:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", new { returnUrl = "/Account/SomeAction" }, new { id = "loginLink" })
```